# Same child, different parents in a TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, treeviewer

I have a JFace `TreeViewer` where the structure is such that a child can have several parents.

When selecting a child in the viewer, I want to get the parent of that selection.

Example, with the following structure:

```
- parent1
    - child
- parent2
    - child
```

When the bottom row is selected, I want to retrieve `parent2`, but `child.getParent()` only gives me the first occurrence of a parent, and does not take which branch I selected in the tree.

Comment: maybe post some code?

Answer (score 3):

Create one marker interface and make all root to implement that interface and on run time add different root model.

Answer (score 1):

The Tree Viewer model doesn't support this.

You will have to add additional methods to your content provider class to return the additional parents.